# How to get kube-dns working in Vagrant cluster using kubeadm and Weave

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, weave, kube-dns

I deployed a few VMs using Vagrant to test kubernetes:
master: 4 CPUs, 4GB RAM
node-1: 4 CPUs, 8GB RAM
Base image: Centos/7.
Networking: Bridged.
Host OS: Centos 7.2

Deployed kubernetes using kubeadm by following [kubeadm getting started guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/). After adding the node to the cluster and installing Weave Net, I'm unfortunately not able to get kube-dns up and running as it stays in a ContainerCreating state:

> ```
> [vagrant@master ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
> NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
> kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-discovery-982812725-0tiiy   1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-dns-2247936740-46rcz        0/3       ContainerCreating   0          1h
> kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-4d8s7           1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-sqea1           1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   weave-net-h1om2                  2/2       Running             0          1h
> kube-system   weave-net-khebq                  1/2       CrashLoopBackOff    17         1h
> ```

I assume the problem is somehow related to the weave-net pod in CrashloopBackoff state which resides on node-1:

```
[vagrant@master ~]$ kubectl describe pods --namespace=kube-system weave-net-khebq
Name:       weave-net-khebq
Namespace:  kube-system
Node:       node-1/10.0.2.15
Start Time: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 07:10:39 +0000
Labels:     name=weave-net
Status:     Running
IP:     10.0.2.15
Controllers:    DaemonSet/weave-net
Containers:
  weave:
    Container ID:   docker://4976cd0ec6f971397aaf7fbfd746ca559322ab3d8f4ee217dd6c8bd3f6ed4f76
    Image:      weaveworks/weave-kube:1.7.0
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:1ac5304168bd9dd35c0ecaeb85d77d26c13a7d077aa8629b2a1b4e354cdffa1a
    Port:       
    Command:
      /home/weave/launch.sh
    Requests:
      cpu:      10m
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 05 Oct 2016 08:18:51 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 05 Oct 2016 08:18:51 +0000
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  18
    Liveness:       http-get http://127.0.0.1:6784/status delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Volume Mounts:
      /etc from cni-conf (rw)
      /host_home from cni-bin2 (rw)
      /opt from cni-bin (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-kir36 (ro)
      /weavedb from weavedb (rw)
    Environment Variables:
      WEAVE_VERSION:    1.7.0
  weave-npc:
    Container ID:   docker://feef7e7436d2565182d99c9021958619f65aff591c576a0c240ac0adf9c66a0b
    Image:      weaveworks/weave-npc:1.7.0
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:4d7f0bd7c0e63517a675e352146af7687a206153e66bdb3d8c7caeb54802b16a
    Port:       
    Requests:
      cpu:      10m
    State:      Running
      Started:      Wed, 05 Oct 2016 07:11:04 +0000
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  0
    Volume Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-kir36 (ro)
    Environment Variables:  <none>
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready     False 
  PodScheduled  True 
Volumes:
  weavedb:
    Type:   EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium: 
  cni-bin:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /opt
  cni-bin2:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home
  cni-conf:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /etc
  default-token-kir36:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-kir36
QoS Class:  Burstable
Tolerations:    dedicated=master:Equal:NoSchedule
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath       Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------       --------    ------      -------
  1h        3m      19  {kubelet node-1}    spec.containers{weave}  Normal      Pulling     pulling image "weaveworks/weave-kube:1.7.0"
  1h        3m      19  {kubelet node-1}    spec.containers{weave}  Normal      Pulled      Successfully pulled image "weaveworks/weave-kube:1.7.0"
  55m       3m      11  {kubelet node-1}    spec.containers{weave}  Normal      Created     (events with common reason combined)
  55m       3m      11  {kubelet node-1}    spec.containers{weave}  Normal      Started     (events with common reason combined)
  1h        14s     328 {kubelet node-1}    spec.containers{weave}  Warning     BackOff     Back-off restarting failed docker container
  1h        14s     300 {kubelet node-1}                Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "weave" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=weave pod=weave-net-khebq_kube-system(d1feb9c1-8aca-11e6-8d4f-525400c583ad)"
```

Listing the containers running on node-1 gives

```
[vagrant@node-1 ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
feef7e7436d2        weaveworks/weave-npc:1.7.0                         "/usr/bin/weave-npc"     About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_weave-npc.e6299282_weave-net-khebq_kube-system_d1feb9c1-8aca-11e6-8d4f-525400c583ad_0f0517cf
762cd80d491e        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0           "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD.d8dbe16c_weave-net-khebq_kube-system_d1feb9c1-8aca-11e6-8d4f-525400c583ad_cda766ac
8c3395959d0e        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-proxy-amd64:v1.4.0   "/usr/local/bin/kube-"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_kube-proxy.64a0bb96_kube-proxy-amd64-4d8s7_kube-system_909e6ae1-8aca-11e6-8d4f-525400c583ad_48e7eb9a
d0fbb716bbf3        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0           "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD.d8dbe16c_kube-proxy-amd64-4d8s7_kube-system_909e6ae1-8aca-11e6-8d4f-525400c583ad_d6b232ea
```

The logs for the first container show some connection errors:

```
[vagrant@node-1 ~]$ sudo docker logs feef7e7436d2
E1005 08:46:06.368703       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:154: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/pods?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1005 08:46:06.370119       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:155: Failed to list *extensions.NetworkPolicy: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1005 08:46:06.473779       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:153: Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1005 08:46:07.370451       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:154: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/pods?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1005 08:46:07.371308       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:155: Failed to list *extensions.NetworkPolicy: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1005 08:46:07.474991       1 reflector.go:214] /home/awh/workspace/weave-npc/cmd/weave-npc/main.go:153: Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I lack the experience with kubernetes and container networking to troubleshoot these issues further, so some hints are very much appreciated.
Observation: All pods/nodes report their IP as 10.0.2.15 which is the local Vagrant NAT address, not the actual IP address of the VMs.

Comment: I use the option for kubeadm init --api-advertise-addresses and point it to not-NAT address (which you need to define in Vagrant file). Although it allows to progress further, it does not fix the issue with weave-net. I have reported the issue here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34101

Comment: I wonder if there is any working step by step instruction on how to get kubernetes cluster up and running on a set of virtual machines? I am happy to downgrade the version of kubernetes if it is an option. I am totally confused with all of these options: kube-deploy, kube-up, and other..

Comment: Thanks. I guess we can conclude that the problem exists for both Ubuntu and Centos deployments then. I did specify the correct master address using --api-advertise-addresses during the init, but I couldn't find a way to set a similar flag for the nodes (if needed at all).

Answer (score 12):

Here is the recipe that worked for me (as of March 19th 2017 using Vagrant and VirtualBox). The cluster is made of 3 nodes, 1 Master and 2 Nodes.

**1)** Make sure you explicitly set the IP of your master node on init

```
kubeadm init --api-advertise-addresses=10.30.3.41
```

**2)** Manually or during provisioning, add to each node's `/etc/hosts` the exact IP that you are configuring it to have. Here is a line you can add in your Vagrant file (node naming convention I use: k8node-$i) :

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sed 's/127\.0\.0\.1.*k8node.*/10.30.3.4#{i} k8node-#{i}/' -i /etc/hosts"
```

Example:

```
vagrant@k8node-1:~$ cat /etc/hosts
10.30.3.41 k8node-1
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

**3)** Finally, all Nodes will try to use the public IP of the cluster to connect to the master (not sure why this is happening ...). Here is the fix for that.

First, find the public IP by running the following on master.

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   1h
```

In each node, make sure that any process using 10.96.0.1 (in my case) is routed to master that is on 10.30.3.41.

So on each Node (you can skip master) use `route` to set the redirect.

```
route add 10.96.0.1 gw 10.30.3.41
```

After that, everything should work ok:

```
vagrant@k8node-1:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   dummy-2088944543-rnl2f             1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   etcd-k8node-1                      1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8node-1            1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8node-1   1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-discovery-1769846148-g8g85    1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-dns-2924299975-7wwm6          4/4       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-proxy-9dxsb                   1/1       Running   0          46m
kube-system   kube-proxy-nx63x                   1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-proxy-q0466                   1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8node-1            1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   weave-net-2nc8d                    2/2       Running   0          46m
kube-system   weave-net-2tphv                    2/2       Running   0          1h
kube-system   weave-net-mp6s0                    2/2       Running   0          1h


vagrant@k8node-1:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS         AGE
k8node-1   Ready,master   1h
k8node-2   Ready          1h
k8node-3   Ready          48m
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [David Bainbridge's repository](https://github.com/davidkbainbridge/k8s-playground).